# Changing whitespaces with minus sign in url

Tags: javascript, url, character-encoding, character

I am struggling with following issue: when user uploads some object to server which has property that contains whitespaces or non Latine characters (like ლ and etc..) that object is saved in db, originally (database i am using supports utf8 encoding) but problem is i want to use that properties (eg name: საქართველო) in url but url does not supports utf8 characters. you would say just replace them but there is another problem: i am using that properties as url params in server side (Expressjs) , and if i change them like `.split(' ').join('-')`, will it affect on my params? if "name" is "hello world" and it changed as "hello-world" will it affect on result? currently whitespaces are changed as `%20` and it works. and second question. how can i change every non latin character to latin character (on my example q-ქ, w-წ and etc but there are many different non latin alphabets too) should i change them with hand or there are some api or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `encodeURI()`

```
encodeURL("საქართველო"); 
//returns "%E1%83%A1%E1%83%90%E1%83%A5%E1%83%90%E1%83%A0%E1%83%97%E1%83%95%E1%83%94%E1%83%9A%E1%83%9D"
```

update

```
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    var charAtIndex = str[i];
    var encodedCharAtIndex = encodeURI(charAtIndex);

    if(charAtIndex != encodedCharAtIndex){
        //char is non-utf8
    }
}
```

Comment: that is returned anyway what i am looking for is საქართველო - saqartvelo 

s-ს
a-ა
q-ქ
a-ა
r-რ
t-თ
v-ვ
e-ე
l-ლ
o-ო

Comment: you could iterate through each char, see if the result of `encodeURI` is different than the char (that would tell you that you're looking at a non-utf8 char) and then you can insert your dashes

Comment: and would that affect on result if that non-utf8 is in database as საქართველო and as saqartvelo in url and i query to search it in db